# Using REGEX_EXTRACT to pull one value but not the other from duplicates

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm having issues pulling specific variables from large text logs.

A normal log looks like this:

```
 metadata {
    unique_id: "88dvsq113-0dcf-410f-84fb-d342076def6f"
    webhook_response_time: 155
    intent_name: "Dogs are the best"
    variable_one: "true"
    variable_two: "false"
    variable_three: "false"
  }
```

I just want to pull the intent_name variable, so I use the regular expression:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(textPayload, r"intent_name:(.+)") AS intent_name FROM table1
```

to pull out just the value "Dogs are the best". Now, in the logs, there are two different parts that include the phrase "intent_name", so this regular expression doesn't pull what I need it to. Here is an example of new logs below:

```
  metadata {
    intent_id: "a664f00f-8105-4e09-bc34-2836dbe89ee1"
    webhook_response_time: 105
    intent_name: "Dogs are the best"
    execution_sequence {
      intent_id: "e231c181-31d9-4bfa-b2d8-7a52314bc628"
      intent_name: "Cats are the best"
      variable_one: "true"
      variable_two: "false"
      variable_three: "false"
    }
```

How do I write an expression to just pull the first intent_name value "Dogs are the best" and not the one not inside the execution_sequence brackets?

Comment: Is it mysql or postgresql? Not clear. Why not just `json_extract(json_data, '$.intent_name')` or `data::json->'intent_name'`? Way easier, less prone to error, cleaner and easier to maintain; winner all around.

Comment: The table I'm pulling it from isn't actually a json, it's a text format imported directly from a JSON file that i no longer have access to.

and this is actually in googleSQL (which is almost identical to postgre) but there was no tag for that!

Comment: @TomUpdike: there is a tag for `google-bigquery`, it that's what you mean by google SQL.

Comment: @GMB i didn't see that, changed. thanks for helping a stackoverflow-newbie out!

Comment: Regex is pretty bad for parsing structured, nested data like this, especially when the nesting can delve to arbitrary levels. In other words, you're likely going to run into trouble if your strategy is to keep track of opening brackets (or parentheses, quotes, etc) and match them with closing brackets to determine whether or not something should be a match. However, if the *indentation* is consistent, you could just use that as your anchor. Something like `r"^ {4}intent_name:(.+)"`

Comment: What's the datatype of the column?

Comment: @RickJames it's a string. Gordon's answer worked for me in this situation, though, I'm working out a way to pull the actual JSON instead of having it convert to make this whole process easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON value would be much easier.  But for the second log format, you could do:

```
select regexp_extract(textPayload, r"""intent_name: ("[^"]+")[\s\S]*execution_sequence""")
from (select '''metadata {
    unique_id: "88dvsq113-0dcf-410f-84fb-d342076def6f"
    webhook_response_time: 155
    intent_name: "Dogs are the best"
    variable_one: "true"
    variable_two: "false"
    variable_three: "false"
  }''' as textPayload union all
      SELECT '''metadata {
    intent_id: "a664f00f-8105-4e09-bc34-2836dbe89ee1"
    webhook_response_time: 105
    intent_name: "Dogs are the best"
    execution_sequence {
      intent_id: "e231c181-31d9-4bfa-b2d8-7a52314bc628"
      intent_name: "Cats are the best"
      variable_one: "true"
      variable_two: "false"
      variable_three: "false"
    }'''
     ) x
```

This does not work on the first format, but you can use a `case` expression if you need to support both.